# Allow specific keyword for all celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have one specific keyword for each task, which is used only in `task_prerun` signal, not in task itself.

I need the way to allow each task accept that argument without adding `**kwarg` to each task.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [message headers](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) for this purpose:

```
result = celery.send_task('add_numbers', args=(1, 2), headers={'special': 'foo'})
```

You should then be able to extract the `special` value in `task_prerun` signal handler like this:

```
def on_task_prerun(self, sender, task_id, task, args, kwargs,
                   **other_kwargs):
    ...
    special_value = sender.request.message.headers.get('special')
    ...
```